# How to merge data efficiently in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to copy some data from `dfb` to `dfa` to replace some rows in `dfa`.

Below is the code.

The code has no problems except using a for loop, which is slow.

Any other faster and more efficient methods?

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
dfb = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')

id = dfa.loc[(dfa['sex'] == 'M') & (dfa['info'] == 'None'), 'id']
id_copy = dfb.loc[(dfb['id'].isin(id))&(dfb['info']!='None'), 'id']

for i in id_copy.values:
    dfa.loc[dfa['id']==i, 'info'] = dfb.loc[dfb['id']==i, 'info']
```

Comment: whats wrong in this? What is input data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `map` and assign it back

```
s=dfa.id.map(dfb.set_index('id').info)
dfa.loc[s.notnull(),'info']=s
```